# Starting afresh with a git repository

Tags: git

I have a git repository, and am about to "start afresh". I have cloned it, zapped everything, committed, and have now a clean fresh repository (hosted on GitHub).

The problem I have is that cloning it takes a while -- only to end up with an empty directory.

Is there a way so that:

- the current master is relegated to a branch
- the new "master" is empty as it should be
- cloning it takes less than 1 second
- people can STILL pull the old master if they want to, although it's meaningless

I don't want to lose the history. But, I also want to relegate it to history, and only get people who REALLY want to see that historical branch.

Comment: What do you mean by "zapped everything"? What do you mean by "master is relagated to a branch"? master is always a branch.

Comment: Why do you clone an existing repository to "start afresh"? Should you not rather create a *new* repository?

Comment: Man, you should keep the old history in a separate repo so that whoever clones the new repo, they don't get all that old stuff by default.

Comment: Are you starting fresh because the repository is slow to clone?

Comment: My existing repository has lots of stars and following. I don't want to get rid of it for that reason -- especially since the rewrite is very much correlated to the original one.

Comment: "zapped everything" = "deleted every single file there". "Master relegated to a branch" = "master becomes "old_project", the new Master is small, and fast to clone

Comment: @Merc People will have to `git clone --single-branch` to get the benefit, and only if `master` is orphaned.

Comment: @Merc Can you provide a link to the repo, please?

Comment: Keeping your stars and followers is somewhat dishonest, if you start over with a fresh repo that shares none of the code that existed when people started/followed your repo. If you really want to do that, make a new repo called "my-library-v1" and push your existing Git repo up there. Then force-push an empty Git repo over top of what you have in your "lots of stars and followers" Github repo now. You'll break things for everybody who has forked your repo to date though.

Comment: My *real* recommendation is stop worrying and leave the history alone. I believe I know what repo you're talking about. It's 20mb and it took me all of 3 seconds to clone it.

Comment: @meagar OK point taken. Maybe to me it's more like "that was a great attempt but the implementation was soooooooo wrong"... I guess everybody will know :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your histories are disconnected, I would suggest archiving the old repository and starting a new one. Keep it available but there's no need to burden the new repository with disconnected history.

However...

> The problem I have is that cloning it takes a while...

This suggests a better solution: clear the big files out of history. Big files should not be committed directly to the repository or you get the problem you're having; cloning is slow because the entire history must be cloned. You can solve this with [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) (git-lfs) which allows you to track the history of big files while keeping the content in cloud storage. That way you don't have to clone every version of that big file, just the latest.

You can [use the BFG Repo Cleaner to transfer your historical big files to git-lfs](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-bfg-to-migrate-a-repo-to-git-lfs/). If you're starting over because your repo has gotten too fat, I would suggest giving that a shot.

---

Otherwise, if you want to use the same repo, I would suggest creating an orphaned branch. This is a branch which has no connection to the other commits in your project.

```
git checkout --orphan <branch name>
```

Your files will still be there, staged, so clear your staging area.

```
git rm --cached -r .
```

And start fresh from there.

However, `git clone` will still get the whole history of the project and it will be just as slow. Folks will need to `git clone --single-branch`. Even if you take this route, I still suggest giving BFG + git-lfs a shot.

Comment: There aren't big files in the repo -- only a long history

Comment: @Merc If it's small files, even a long history shouldn't take that long to clone, for example, [ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby) is 219 MB. And cloning needs only to be done once. Can you show us your `git clone` output? That will give a better idea of the scale.